# Can I increase the RAM of a microcontroller by using CPU's RAM?

Tags: microcontroller

I was making a home automation project in which I will make voice operated appliances without the use of a mobile app. To process the real time audio I need more RAM in my microcontroller, so can I increase the RAM using an old CPU's RAM??

Comment: Huh? What "old CPU"?

Comment: Please state your type of microcontroller and type of RAM. The chance of success of any microcontroller design depends highly on what peripherals you use, and how you use them.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Jasmeet probably has an old PC laptop / desktop that he wants to pull the RAM (DDR, DDR2) from in order to increase the uC's RAM.

Comment: Which microcontroller, and how much extra RAM do you need?

Comment: Microcontrollers generally do not have an external memory interface (some do but that is atypical), and if they did would that match the mysterious memory you are talking about?  Odds are very very unlikely. You want more ram look at the datasheet and order the part with more ram. Or at the line chart for that vendor and go to the next size chip up, the peripherals are likely to be more common (portable code) than not, but that is also part of your research. You can ponder spi or i2c memory, but it really depends on what you are trying to do and if this is the right solution in the first place

Comment: I once salvaged SRAM chips from the CPU cache of a 486-class PC with the intention to use them as external RAM with an AVR ATmega. (Never needed external RAM, so dropped the project.) So, yes, if you find a 486 machine or older you may find suitable chips to use for your uC.

Answer (score 1):

**Probably not**

There are a great many types of microcontroller on the market, and a great many types of RAM. Without knowing which micro and which RAM you're talking about, we can't tell if they are compatible.  But if you pair up a randomly selected micro with some old RAM you had lying about the chances of them being compatible is slim.  If by CPU you mean some RAM from a PC, the chances are basically nil.